# Facebook Batch query for posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using below query get page post results and comment count in batch query POST method.

> batch : [{"name":"post-resultset","method":"GET","relative_url":"me/posts?offset=0&limit=2"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"fql?q=SELECT post_id, comment_info from stream where post_id IN ({result=post-resultset:$.data.*.id})"}]

I got response with error code 400

> {"error": {"message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected '_435851216505244' at position 74.","type": "OAuthException","code": 601 }}

What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the post_id on **post-resultset:$.data.*.id** does not surrounded by quotes, such as

"relative_url":"fql?q=SELECT post_id, comment_info from stream where post_id IN (\"1234567_435851216505244\")"

I think it's a facebook bug and you should report the bug on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

[image]

Comment: Thanks. [{"omit_response_on_success":false,"name":"post-resultset","method":"GET","relative_url":"me/posts"},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"fql?q=SELECT comment_info from stream where post_id IN (\'{result=post-resultset:$.data.*.id}\')"}] this query is working for me.

Comment: @PonmalaK hi, i'm curious how it's works for you, because it doesn't works even using Graph API explorer